# Subquery for MySQL WHERE clause to exclude data

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a query that retrieves a list of names.  I need to modify the query by adding a subquery that will exclude `t1.name` if it appears within t2.exclude.  I need some help with constructing the subquery, which I understand will go into the `WHERE` clause below:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM t1
WHERE *** t1.name is not in t2.exclude ***
```

What is the correct syntax for the subquery that I need?  Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple ways to do this using `not exists`, `not in` or `outer join null` checks.  However, without understanding your table structures, it's difficult to provide the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM t1
WHERE t1.name NOT IN (SELECT t2.name from t2)
```

you'll exclude all t1.name that exist in t2.name

**EDIT 1**

Doing some tests i end up in a very weird query, but it works, here you go:

```
SELECT * from t1
WHERE t1.name NOT IN (
    SELECT t1.name FROM t1, t2
    WHERE t1.name LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.name ,'%')
)
```

if you're wondering how it works, it does an `inverse whitelist` check

1. Select ALL names from Both tables (cartesian product problem here)
2. get names from t1 that **LOOKS LIKE** t2 names (whitelisting)
3. then use that list of t1 names to filter the original t1 result. (blacklisting)

tldr; you do a While-black-list over the two tables.

Check out the test on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a1ce/32)

Comment: Thanks @josegomezr.  This works for full matches on the name field, but what would I do for partial matches?  Need to use INSTR in some way...

Comment: check it out! now should do the trick (i made up those fancy terms)